# IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch when trying to drag a popupwindow

Tags: javafx, drag, popupwindow

When I try to drag a popupwindow an exception appears:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

I designed the popwindow in SceneBuilder and added two methods for the anchorpane:

1. `setOnMousePressed` -> returns the position of the popupwindow
2. `setOnMouseDragged` ->returns the exception.

The first method works fine and the second not.
As I can't find a solution although the topic has been covered, I would be very thankful for some help.

Code of the poupwindow:

```
private static double xOffset = 0; 
private static double yOffset = 0;

@FXML
void setOnMouseDragged(MouseDragEvent event) {
    Stage window=(Stage)((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    window.setX(event.getScreenX() + xOffset);
    window.setY(event.getScreenY() + yOffset);
}

@FXML
void setOnMousePressed(MouseEvent event) { 
    Stage window=(Stage)((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    xOffset = window.getX() - event.getScreenX();
    yOffset = window.getY() - event.getScreenY();
    System.out.println("setOnMouseDraggedx:"+xOffset+" yOffset:"+yOffset);
//this method works and prints out x:-419.0 yOffset:-31.0
}
```

Comment: You're not by chance importing the `awt` or `dom` `MouseEvent` class instead of the correct one?

Comment: Posting the stack trace may help to answer your question.

Comment: [mcve] please ...

Answer (score 0):

The `EventHandler` of the [`Node#onMouseDragged`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#onMouseDraggedProperty) property handles `MouseEvent`s, not `MouseDragEvent`s. The former cannot be cast to the latter.

> #### onMouseDragged
>
> ```
> public final ObjectProperty<EventHandler<? super MouseEvent>> onMouseDraggedProperty
> ```
>
> Defines a function to be called when a mouse button is pressed on this `Node` and then dragged.

Using:

```
@FXML
void setOnMouseDragged(MouseEvent event) { /* code */ }
```

Should solve the `IllegalArgumentException`.

---

Note that `setOnMouseDragged` and `setOnMousePressed` are odd names for methods that don't **set** the event handlers, but instead actually handle their respective events.

Comment: Hello Slaw, I am sorry, but I think that this is exactly what I have in my code (see above). I imported javafx.scene.input.MouseDragEvent and javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent.

Comment: Here is the stack trace:

Comment: Yes... but my answer explains that `MouseDragEvent` is the _wrong_ type to use.

Comment: setOnMouseDraggedx:-450.0 yOffset:-32.0
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
 ..... and so on

Comment: Just to reiterate: `Node#onMouseDragged` uses a `MouseEvent` **not** a `MouseDragEvent`.

Comment: Hello Slaw, thank you for your patience. I did not realize that I was using the wrong mouse event. Now it works. Thank you once again. Best regards from Hamburg,  Marcus